# Has Sun Tzu ever advocated for something that in modern society is a war crime, or what has Sun Tzu ever said about war crimes?

Tags: ancient-history, war, political-history, literature, ancient-china

I've read The Art of War 3x, but I didn't yet know the concept of 'war crime'. So I never really paid much attention to the text in that regard.

**Question**: Has Sun Tzu ever advocated for something that in modern society is a war crime (and then like 'oh it's not or it wasn't thought to be a war crime at their time in ancient China'), or what has Sun Tzu ever said about war crimes?

**Guess**:

For example, there's this thing which seems to relate to the [false flag war crime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_flag):

> Therefore in chariot fighting, when ten or more chariots have been taken, those should be rewarded who took the first. Our own flags should be substituted for those of the enemy, and the chariots mingled and used in conjunction with ours.

But then again the very next sentence is

> The captured soldiers should be kindly treated and kept.

At the very least Sun Tzu definitely disagrees with the saying "The only war crime is losing."

Comment: Which question do you want answered?  Where do you get the idea that this has anything to do with false flag?  Hasn't this question already been asked and closed?

Comment: @MCW Thank you for asking. Edited post.

Comment: Military equipment belonging to an adverse party (and which is not personal property of POWs) may be seized as war booty. It is long-standing practice and in accordance with modern rules of war to re-use and incorporate captured vehicles, tanks, planes, ships, artillery pieces, etc into ones own forces if deemed useful. This includes applying the appropriate military markings of the capturing side prior to re-deployment on the battlefield. The quoted passage from Sun Tzu seems to describe the same process, thus no war crime.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you perhaps reading the "Our own flags should be substituted for those of the enemy..." part as "we should put the enemy's flags on our chariots"? Because I think it's saying "replace the enemy's flags on the captured chariots with our own flags", i.e. you shouldn't fly a false flag.

Comment: What Sun Tzu advocates regarding the chariots is exactly what is done (and is, in fact, required) in the modern day with captured tanks and planes. For example, the Nazis [captured, repainted, and used many Soviet T-34 tanks](https://www.rbth.com/history/333625-germans-made-use-soviet-tank). Soviet symbols were replaced with Swastikas and Iron Crosses. Treating captured soldiers "kindly" is also consistent with modern-day rules on how to treat POW's. Your quotations seem to indicate that Sun Tzu's views largely match those of today.

Comment: For aircraft, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Moolah#/media/File:USAF_MiG-15.jpg) is a North Korean MiG-15 that was captured by the USA and repainted in US markings for flight tests. [Here's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Moolah) the history of the plane itself. Repainting a plane with new national markings is functionally equivalent to swapping one flag for another on a chariot.

Comment: I think the premise of the question confuses "substitute *for*" with "substitute *with*", which have opposite meanings.

Answer (score 2):

What Sun Tzu is describing wrt chariots is the SOP in all armies around the world. E.g., Wehrmacht used a lot of captured T-34s:

[image]

note the cross on the turret.

Other armies (and navies!) did the same.

> Our own flags should be substituted for those of the enemy

This is exactly what makes it legitimate: the captured equipment is marked as ours and used.

*False flag* is when you dress your soldiers in the enemy uniform, see, e.g., [Operation Greif](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Greif).

Comment: The Soviets returned that favor: [Captured Panzer IV](https://www.worldwarphotos.info/wp-content/gallery/germany/tanks/panzer-iv/Panzer-IV_36.jpg)...

Comment: This doesn't really answer his question, even if it does clarify his mistaken assumption.

Comment: This is also happening in 2022 in Ukraine. There are garages that repair captured Russian vehicles and repaint them with Ukrainian military markings in preparation for deployment.